# know on which table 'begin tran' has happened or find which table is locked / deadlocked

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am new to c# and sql server. I'am using SQL Server 2008 and I have 126 tables in my database.

There are 7 transaction tables on which insert/update query fires frequently as there are 30-40 users for my application.

I have written `BEGIN TRAN` before every query and `COMMIT` at the end of the query.
Now many-a-times I get error 'Timeout expired ...' when any random user tries to open a form or save some data.

I have written `ROLLBACK` in my triggers if the trigger throws an error.

But I could not identify on which table `BEGIN TRAN` has happened or which table is deadlocked.

I have made sure that my connection is proper and is open, then I'am getting this error too
and I couldn't identify from where it is comming.

Does anyone have any idea from where this 'Timeout expired' error is comming and can suggest me some way out?

Answer (score 0):

> Does any one have any idea from where this 'Timeout expired' error is coming and can suggest me some way out.

One of the **possible** reasons is that the transaction cannot acquire lock on some resource(table, row, ...).
In that case you may try to increase the [LOCK_TIMEOUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182729.aspx) or change the [isolation level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)(if acceptable).

I would suggest reading [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) article.